# JMETER : During load run , few samples are failing while running with multilple users

Tags: jmeter

This is my Test plan

Thread Group 
 - Only Once Controller 
 
  *             login 
 -Loop Controller 
   *            operations in GUI .every iteration picks unique data from csv 
  - Only Once Controller 
    *            logout 
I am using in GUI and Summary report .

This is working fine with 1 or 2 users. When I triggered with 10 users , sometime few samples are failing. I dont know where to check for logs.I enables log level to DEBUG and able to see the logs but not much info. Is there a way to check for screenshots on errors what exactly happened in browser that time? . Also how to generate jtl file? error files in Jmeter. Please help.

Comment: 1) In View Results Listeners, you can monitor the web pages results in HTML/Raw Data too.
2) In the view results tree or summary report in the file name you can give the file name and path 
eg: C:/users/data1/results.jtl

Comment: Thankyou ! can we use view result listeneres with multiple users ( like 100 users) . In this case what to be used to see the errors?please help

Comment: In View Results tree listener, you can get the each user Request and Response.

Comment: While running i saw few samples failed in view result tree listener , then after the run is completed , only few latest samples are shown in view result tree . how to get all the results in view result tree?

I exported the results to .jtl file and oppened in summary report. I am seeing for few samples the error % . How to get what is the failure and which user failed and other details from summart report or from .jtl file.Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use JMeter GUI for load testing, it's designed for tests development and debugging only, start your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. When test finishes you can open the `result.jtl` file with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it

---

If at that stage there are failures you can temporarily enable JMeter to store all the request and response data by adding the next lines to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html):

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

Don't forget to delete previous `result.jtl` before the execution.